# WPF:ScrollViewer content not aligning left

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a Scrollviewer which contains a grid ,

Something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="dcScrollViewer">
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
             <!--Some Content-->
        <Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

the problem is when the view is getting loaded the scrollviewer content does not align left, The horizontal scrollbar shifts little right

I even tried to set the horizontal offset by :

```
dcScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
```

What am I doing incorrectly, I want the alignment of the horizontal scollbar to be forced to the left on the initial load of the View?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities. I don't know precisely what you're running into here because there isn't enough information.

1. Make sure your left margin on the content is 0.
2. Make sure your left padding on the scroll viewer/content is 0.
3. Make sure you don't have an errant border (or some invisible element) adding width you don't want. If you do, make it small or make it go away.
4. Examine your visual tree using a tool like Snoop to understand where the extra space is coming from. Setting different background colors on different elements can prove useful in this context as well.
5. You can always cheat by setting your left margin on the content to a negative value. If your grid is properly aligned, you can even leave ClipToBounds = "true". (Though I don't recall ever needing to set this-- perhaps it's related to your problem?)

Comment: i tried giving margin, padding to 0,even tried with negative margin, no border or invisible element is present.Still no luck!!

Comment: This is why I suggested using Snoop to actually look at your visual tree. It's an invaluable tool when working with WPF (and a real leg up over doing this same work in uwp, imho)

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin="-10,0,0,0" to Grid. That Should Work!